# Android: instantiating a class extending view

Tags: android, android-manifest, instance

I have an Android class called `DrawBall` which extends view, however when I try to instantiating the `DrawBall` class from an Activity (`Display`) it crashes my application.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the Manifest file, however being new to Android I can't work it out.

```
public class Display extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(new DrawBall(this));      
    }
}
```

The `DrawBall` class looks like this:

```
public class DrawBall extends View
{
    private Bitmap Ball;

    public DrawBall(Context context)
    {
         super(context);
         Ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_sphere);
    }

    //@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);       
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        canvas.drawBitmap(Ball, 400, 400, null);
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to initialise a view in the Manifest file (providing the above code is correct)?

Comment: Don't call `setContentView()` twice.

Comment: You know calling twice setContentView will override the first one

Comment: I'm aware of the two setContentView lines, I was just planning to comment out the irrelevant line in order to test what was displayed. Problem is that I can't test because the code causes errors in the application :(

Comment: is there any logcat error ?? or java file is showing error on "Display" ??

Comment: canvas.drawBitmap(Ball, 100, 100, null); try this & dont forget to implement "onSensorChanged" & "onAccuracyChanged" these two methods of "SensorEventListener" in Display activity

Comment: I have both onSensorChanged and onAccuracyChanged methods implemented, but I left them out so the code could be understood a little easier. The code as is compiles fine, however when it comes time to execute, the Application is "forced to close - run time error". I really think it has something to do with the manifest class tag, as the software runs fine when the DrawBall class isn't called.